# How to put linebreaks on dynamically generated javascript code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Working on ASP.net website. In my webpage I'm dynamically writing some javascript in the code-behind code. How can I put linebreaks at certain points so that if I do a 'view source' of the page it is more readable? Right now all the dynamic js code is one one line.

I've tried appending `<BR/>` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<br />` is html element which will not help you at this point. you can use `Environment.NewLine` to add these line-breaks: example code will be like the following:

```
StringBuilder strBuilderJS = new StringBuilder(); 
strBuilderJS.Append("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + 
                    "$(WireEvents_" + this.ID + ");" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "function WireEvents_" + this.ID + "(){" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "    alert('stuff');");
strBuilderJS.Append(Environment.NewLine + "}</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Response.Write()`, you can use `\r\n` to add a newline in your HTML output.

Example:

```
Response.Write("<div>\r\nThis is my text.\r\n</div>"
```

This will appear in the HTML as:

```
<div>
This is my text.
</div>
```